# is it safe to use baseclass in vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

i found that in cpp i could not cast a vector of objects like in java (sorry i promise i'll never mention that language again, lol)

...unless i used pointers, but from what i saw on other posts, it seems that it needs a lot of code to do such a simple thing

so...

```
class ConnectedSentence 
{
    vector<Sentence*> sentences;
    ...
```

but it sometimes needs to be returned as a more general vector
(where Sentence derives Node)

```
    vector<Node*> getSentencesAsNodes()
    {
        return sentences;    <----compile error of course
    }
```

so i though of using

```
vector<Node*> sentences
```

instead in the class, meaning that i would have to cast to class Sentence every time i wanted to use it...
but i was wondering if it was safe to use a very base class to store the data ? (or a void* pointer)

or maybe with a union type

```
union unifiedObjectPointer
{
    Node* nodes;
    Sentences* sentences;
}
```

i am not confident in the way i want to approach this problem (i am not really used to c++)

any advice would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing pointers to the base class is safe. Storing the objects by base class value, is not safe (it causes slicing).

If your design is good, you should never have to down-cast when you use the pointers; you should have all needed behavior exposed by virtual functions.

Also, do not use void* for storage, unless you're confident you will never have to downcast to any other type again (in other words, unless you are interested in the addresses themselves, and nothing else).

Code:

```
class ConnectedSentence 
{
    vector<Node*> sentences;
    ...

    const vector<Node*>& getSentencesAsNodes() const // return by const reference
                                                     // from a const function
    {
        return sentences; // now fine
    }

    vector<Node*>& getSentencesAsNodes() // ... or by return by non-const ref.
                                         // from a non-const function
    {
        return sentences; // now fine
    }
};
```

If you return the vector by value, a copy of the vector will be made and returned.

**Edit**: Consider using either `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>` instead of `std::vector<Node*>`. This will make the code safer (exception safe) and simpler (you won't have to delete the nodes manually).